# Open new Window in Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I m new in Spring Framework.I want to cal a new window on click on link, but that page contains data retriving through database.How to do that?? and that data is retrived by controller having model and view method type.

Answer (score 1):

You do eactly as you would do to open the page in the same window, except that the link should contain a `target="_blank"` attribute:

```
<%-- define the URL of the link --%>
<c:url var="theUrl" value="/someAction">
    <c:param name="someParamName" value="someParamValue">
</c:url>

<%-- generate the link --%>
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(theUrl)}" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Arjan Tijms: Thanx for ur respone, it helped out.
But can you suggest me how to show the same page in lightbox???

Comment: lightbox is used to display images, isn't it?

Comment: no it is used to display text and links whixh perform actions]